# How to create Embedded System Program from Scratch using Keil µVision?

Tags: electrical-engineering, embedded-systems

I have been learning the program embedded systems using Keil µVision 4.7 free version from Mentor graphic. So far all the learning has be using projects that have been already pre-defined. This has worked well so far. I would like to take the next step. Below are some of the several tutorial that I have tried with out much success.

- [Creating Applications using Keil µVision IDE from Mentor Graphic](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/uv4/uv4_creating_apps.htm)
- [Create a new project using Keil uVision4 for STM32 (tutorial)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z_BwDGf7FTs)
- [Getting Started with Keil uVision](http://www.circuitstoday.com/getting-started-with-keil-uvision)

What the minimum step to create a new an Embedded System project using Kiel µVision (Including defining the micro controller, and even setting up the debugger) so issues describe below are avoided?

Comment: This is much too broad of a question. There are likely many tutorials available, but this site is not for tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some steps for a ARM Cortex-M4

1. Close your current project in keil µVision, menu: projects->close project
2. Select "New uVision Project..." from "Project" menu
   [image]
3. open an empty new one, menu: projects->create a new µVision project
   [image]
4. Select a Target processor
   [image]
5. You get a popup that asks if you want to copy the startup assembler file into your project startup startup_xxxx.s.
   [image]
6. now you see the empty project with just the startup file included.
   [image]
7. Project is ready for embedded software development. It is good idea to rename "Target 1" and "Source Group 1" that describes the project

Right click on Target 1 > Select Manage Project Items -> Update Project Targets, Groups and Files
[image]

8. In order to startup our micro-controller, we need to add 'system_.c' file to our project. Keil already has this file defined. To add manually, Right-click on our "Startup" group and select "Add Existing Files to Group 'Startup'...":

[image]
a.  Keil already have common startup files for some microcontrollers. They are stored at /Keil/ARM/Startup folder
[image]
b.  From there, for my LaunchPad I will move to TI folder, and then TM4C123 folder:
[image]
c.  And there i can see my system_TM4C123.c file:
[image]

9. now you need to add the copied file into the project. project->manage->components,.. or simply click the icon with the three coloured boxes
   add there the startup_TM4C123.c file. you should then see it listed on the left window bar.
10. now create your xxx.c file containing the main procedure.
     you need to add it to the project again, like you did in the previous step.
11. and now you need to set some registers in the controller. for now you can simply do that at the beginning of the main procedure.

Note: Most the screen shots were created by screen name vasily.sib on piazza forum. I copied these improved them for my purpose.